# return a json value from an mvc controller method in php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller

i would like to get an json type value from an mvc controller method. everything is correct but an error occures'.

my jquery ajax function:

```
function user_login(uname,pass){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/s/login_request',
        type:'POST',
        data:{uname:uname,pass:pass},
        dataType:"json",
        cache: false,
    })
    .done(function(response){
         //do something   
         alert('1234');
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus){
        alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    });
}
```

and here is my php code(mvc controller method):

```
function login_request(){
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('testvalue'));   
}
```

when i run the code, the .fail section executed and the following value was returned:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"[\"testvalue\"]","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

how can i solve this? thanks...

Comment: Could be the trailing comma after cache: false

Comment: inspect actual request in browser dev tools for clues.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/s/login_request',
    type:'POST',
    data:{uname:uname,pass:pass},
    dataType:"json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) { },
    fail: function(xhr, status) { alert(JSON.stringify(xhr)) },
    error: function() { },
    complete: function() { alert('1234') }
});
```